# How to generate 64 bit random numbers?

Tags: c++, random, universal-hashing

I'm implementing universal hashing and using the following universal hash function :

> h(k)=((A*k)mod 2^64) rsh 64-r

where A is a random number between

> 2^61 and 2^62.

The `rand()` function in *C++* has return type *integer* and it can't generate that big numbers. So how can i generate random numbers in this range? (numbers should be very random i.e. every number should have equal probability to be selected)

Note:

```
long long int random=rand();
```

doesn't work as the number returned by `rand` is *int*.

Comment: Read about [the new PRNG support that was introduced in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: If you had a good PRNG at hand (and not `std::rand()`) you could just generate N bits out of it and concatenate them. Or generate M bits at once, and concatenate them. Since if its good, each bit has the same probability, as such concatenating them is safe.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In *C++11* you can use the [random header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) along with a [64-bit instance of std::mersenne_twister_engine](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) this should do what you want (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee6a28b593f88ca7)*):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937_64 e2(rd());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<long long int> dist(std::llround(std::pow(2,61)), std::llround(std::pow(2,62)));

    std::cout << std::llround(std::pow(2,61)) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << std::llround(std::pow(2,62)) << std::endl; 

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
            std::cout << dist(e2)<< ", " ;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

If *C++11* is not an option then it seems there is source code available for [several 64-bit Mersenne Twister implementations](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html).

Answer (score 8):

```
((long long)rand() << 32) | rand()
```

EDIT: that's assuming that rand() produces 32 random bits, which it might not.

Comment: Note that this won't actually produce very good results. (because std::rand is terrible) +1

Comment: Note: On a crap-tastic MS VC++ environment where RAND_MAX is a legacy pitiful 0x7FFF, this won't work.

Comment: @Whoz: It is just as crap-tastic on every other implementation I've seen. `std::rand` is 99.9% of the time powered by a linear congruential generator of some description -- the range that it returns is a minor problem in comparison.

Comment: @BillyONeal If limited by 0x7FFF, its a *huge* problem in this case, as the numbers generated would not be in the desired range *at all*, much less uniformly distributed in said-range (2^61..2^62).

Comment: @Whoz: If `rand` is an LCG (which again, it is on every implementation I've ever seen), then it is not uniformly distributed within the range defined by `RAND_MAX`. And so the result here will not be uniformly distributed anyway.

Comment: @BillyONeal oh I never claimed it was the *only* thing holding this answer back from being workable. I'd implement this as Shafik has done without doubt. My point was this is *dependent* on top-range of RAND_MAX, which isn't always where people think it is. But I certainly agree with you as well; even if the top-end were 0x7FFFFFFFF (as it is on most sane 32-bit `int` platforms save for MS) this still suffers from the uniformity issue with a LCG that you describe.

Comment: @Whoz: (In particular LCGs have a period equaling their output size. Thus, given what the upper 32 bits are in this example, the lower 32 bits will always be the same; there are only 32 bits worth of possible outputs here, even if `RAND_MAX` is `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.)

Comment: `rand()` doesn't produce 32 bits on any platform (since it produces a non-negative value for a signed type). It produces 31 or 15 bits on popular implementations. So even if `rand()` produces 31 bits, the values produces by this answer will always have bits 15 and 31 set to 0.