# How to Generate distinct large random number/keys in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, numbers, unsigned-long-long-int

generate large  random number in  c++ which is closely near to pow(2, 64)-1.

Explain that problem that let say we should generate n random numbers in which mostly is big and stored them in a array.

Comment: Have you try something ?

Comment: Knowing "_How to ask a question on Stack Overflow and what_" is the first thing to do.

Comment: Come up with code first, then we'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

The question really needs more clarification. What is 'closely near'? Are you trying to generate weighted random values or is (2^64)-1 the maximum value?

For the sake of providing an answer I assume the latter and that your random value is always positive:

Generation could be done using the standard library:
[How to generate 64 bit random numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096015/how-to-generate-64-bit-random-numbers)

You need to use uint64_t or similar to store the number. Any smaller and the data could overflow the int bound.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow